# Can install my wireless adapter and can't install ndiswrapper

Tags: wireless, adapter, ndiswrapper

I have read multiple help threads already and they don't seem to work for me.

Can someone walk me through it to fix this problem?
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I'm posting this from my ipad I'm sorry. 
I'm dyslexic which makes it like 10x harder to copy everything to my ipad to post.

Lsusb:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTfjU.jpg can't post images until 10 reputation points.

And I followed the instructions on this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221251

Which told me to follow the follow command and here is the result.
i.stack.imgur.com/CS9bn.jpg (need 10 points to post 2 links lol)

Edit:
I should also let you guys know I just typed

```
Ndiswrapper
```

And I got to told to install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common
```

And I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package ndiswrapper-common
```

I also haven't had internet from the installation.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you edited your question to add all the details of your device from `lspci` or `lsusb` as well as a summary of what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

try this guide. I managed to install my wifi adapter, but it doesnt work after reboot:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper